# SQL Year Date Query

Tags: sql

I am working on a SQL server and I have a list of dates in the format of 
2015-03-17 how would I query the database so that only events that occurred in 2015 show up

Comment: Please try something on your own first.  This is an extremely basic query that is readily available on Google and in any SQL Server resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add this in your queries:

```
YEAR(DateField) = 2015
```

Comment: Actually, you shouldn't, and [**here's why**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable).

Answer (score 3):

You might get better results by trying:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE DateField >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00'
    and DateField < '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
```

This has a higher chance of being "[**sargable**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable)", if you have a index on that column, rather than applying a function over your `DateField`, which will most certainly bypass using the index.

Comment: Got it, I see your update :). Deleted my comment and tossed in an upvote to get you positive. This is a nice answer.

Comment: @JNevill Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from YourTable where Year(SomeDateField)=2015
```

Answer (score 0):

Select * from YourTable where Date(SomeDateField)>2015 And Date(SomeDateField)<2016;
This helps find date between two years 2015 and 2016

Comment: Why? Why not just `=2015`?

Comment: He has explicitly given date so date can't be taken directly 2015.